# I get the following Error in Node.js `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, nodejs-server

```
C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\nlp_samurai\nlp_samurai\>npm install --save
```

If I run this command in Node.js Terminal I get the following Error   `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`..I need to run this command to install all the required Node.js modules for a project from github..[Check the project In this link for better understanding](https://github.com/arthurratz/nlpsamurai-0.0.10#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Installing,nlp_samurai%5Cnode_modules%20folder.)

Comment: The answer below is correct, alternatively you can also give the directory as a parameter like this: `npm install -prefix "C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\nlp_samurai\nlp_samurai\" -save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is trying to call the command `npm install --save` with the directory name in it, instead of running the command **from** the directory.

The command mentioned on the project's page is meant to install the projects dependencies. It has to be run in the directory `nlp_samurai\nlp_samurai\`. The easiest way to get there is to call `cd [directory name]` (Change Directory) and then run `npm install --save`.

You can check out [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/cmd/example/8646/navigating-in-cmd) to learn more about navigation in the Windows command line.